# Integrals - Permitted Change of variables and Limits

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the following integral

F = $\int_0^\pi dy \\$

The value of F = $\pi$

I want to know where I am going wrong when I do the following:

Substitute $x = \sin(y)$ 
When I do that the integral becomes:
$F = \int_0^0 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
Why is this particular form of change of variables not valid?

Answer (score 3):

When you make the substitution, you get $y = \sin^{-1} x$, but the range of arcsine is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Therefore, there is no $x$ such that $\sin^{-1} x = \pi \notin [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so your substitution is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look deeper into the substitution.  If $x=\sin y, dx=\cos ydy$.  Now

$$\int dy=\int\sec y\cos ydy$$

Since $dx=\cos ydy$, we need to figure out $\sec y$ in terms of $x$.  From $0$ to $\frac\pi2$, we have $\sec y=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.  However, from $\frac\pi2$ to $\pi$, cosine is negative.  Therefore,

$$F=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\int_1^0-\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the change-of-variable function is problematic here; it is not defined at $x = 1$. (As $y$ passes from $0$ to $\pi$, we have $x$ passing from $0$ to $0$ but through $1$.)